# Clickable song progress bar Soundmanager2

Tags: javascript, audio, soundmanager2

This is my code for the current and loading bar:

```
whileloading: function() {
     $(".loadBar").css('width', ((this.bytesLoaded / this.bytesTotal) * 100) + '%');
},

whileplaying: function() {
     $(".progBar").css('width', ((this.position/this.duration) * 100) + '%');
},
```

How can i change the current audio position when i click on the current time bar?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var that = this;
$("#ProgressAndLoadBarContainer").click(function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    var relX = e.pageX - parseFloat($this.css("left"));
    var time = track_duration*(relX / $this.width());
    that.setPosition(time);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach IMHO is to use the offsetX property. Unfortunately while that works in Chrome, it does not in Firefox (see http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/mouse-position/ for some background on cross-browser issues). The following works for me:

```
var pBar = document.createElement('progress');
$(pBar).click(function(evt) {
    var clickX = evt.offsetX;
    if(clickX == undefined){
        // welcome to Firefox
        var rect = evt.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        clickX = evt.clientX - rect.left;
    }
    var percent = clickX / evt.target.offsetWidth;
    console.log("pBar click at " + clickX+", "+percent+"%");
});
```

You could also use the slider widget provided by jQuery UI.